# How can I set again the sendlog for a triggeredsend?

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

I was getting an error for my triggered sends and after consulting Support, they got the error "Send Loging Error: The send log data extension was not found." from the logs.

Is this the TriggeredSendDataExtension? How can I change the sendlogs for my triggeredsend?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd continue the conversation with Support. When Send Logging's enabled, triggered sends and everything else logs send details if the Send Log DE's been created, otherwise no send logging takes place. Have you deleted your send logging data extension? Try creating a new one using the Email Send Logging data extension template and re-publish your triggered sends, but in principal, this is one for Support to figure out.

Comment: Did you move the sendlog to a shared folder or delete it?